# Adjective describing a project/goal that is not easy to collaborate on

Tags: single-word-requests

Example usage:

At first we attempted to cheat by dividing the problems between us. However, the test wasn't (adjective) because most of the solutions depended on the answer from the previous problem.

A noun with similar meaning to "ease of collaboration" would also work.

Comment: Dividing items among people for independent solution is the antithesis of collaboration.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to say something like "it wasn't easy to do so" or "it didn't work very well"?  (I'm not trying to propose these exact wordings―I just don't understand the motivation for asking for a single-word adjective here.)

Comment: I provided a suggested edit based on the selected answer and the OP's comment on such.  (I don't think the selected answer is necessarily the best way to handle this, but it does clarify what the OP was looking for.)

Comment: @bib Dividing a task into subtasks and distributing among individuals is certainly a form of collaboration **and** from one perspective it's anthesis.

Comment: 2. Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. The way the question is currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However, the test wasn't ***decomposable*** because most of the solutions depended on the answer from the previous problem.

Comment: What does "*decomposable*" mean? Cite to some authority, please.

Comment: Thanks, that fits the example sentence well, but not so much the title. (my fault)

Comment: I think that plugging in *decomposable* into the OP's gapped sentence is very clever--I would never have thought if it. Though I think it results in a statement that would be unclear to many readers or hearers. Further, it seems to me vulnerable to charges that it is an incomplete idea or that the idea could be more carefully expressed. In fact, the test *can* be decomposed into problems, but doing so is unworkable as a tactic for dividing labor.

Comment: The question is unclear and at odds with its header. The OP appears to be happy with an answer, but I would close without a revision of the question, which might helpfully also show why the question is being asked or in what way and context the answer would be used.

Answer (score 1):

Divisible. [Sectionable](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sectionable). Amenable to teamwork.

Answer (score 0):

As a computer scientist, I want to say the problem is *not parallelizable*. The problem can't be broken down into concurrently executable chunks.